# How is $\lambda x.x^2$ a valid lambda expression?

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus):

- a variable, $x$, is itself a valid lambda term
- if $t$ is a lambda term, and $x$ is a variable, then $(λ x . t )$ is a lambda term (called a lambda abstraction);
- if $t$ and $s$ are lambda terms, then ( $t$ $s$ ) ($ts$) is a lambda term (called an application).

How can $\lambda x.x^2$ be a valid lambda term if $x^2$ is not, as it is not a variable and is neither an abstraction nor an application?

Comment: Therefore $λx.x^2$ is not *pure* lambda calculus. For *pure* lambda calculus, look at [Lambda Calculus § Arithmetic in lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Arithmetic_in_lambda_calculus) on en.wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the actual context, but it appears that this is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

I would interpret it as $$\lambda x.\ \mathrm{m}\ x\ x$$ where $\mathrm{m}$ stands for the multiplication operation in context (or $\lambda x.\ \mathrm{p}\ x\ 2$ where $\mathrm{p}$ is the power opertion and $2$ stands for the term corresponding to numeral $2$).

Please note, that we use syntactic sugar often and *pure* lambda calculus is rather rare, e.g.,
$$\mathrm{let}\ i = \lambda x.\ x\ \mathtt{in}\ i\ \ i$$
and 
$$i\ i\ \mathrm{where}\ i = \lambda x.\ x$$
both actually stand for
$$ (\lambda i.\ i\ i)\ (\lambda x.\ x) $$
which is a way harder to read. It is quite inconvienient to use just *pure* lambda calculus.

Other than that, sometimes lambda calculus gets extended, but then the context should specify how we are to interpret such extensions.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$